# Declaration does not declare anything C++ error

Tags: c++, nios

I'm having a problem with the NIOS 2 SD Card Libary.

The problem is referenced to this part of the libary:

```
#ifndef bool
    typedef enum e_bool { false = 0, true = 1 } bool;
#endif
```

The NIOS Eclipse compiler resulted me this error:

```
declaration does not declare anything
```

What might be causing this issue?

Comment: Are you compiling the code as C, or C++?  It looks like it should be compiled as C since C++ has always had a bool type.

Comment: My Main file is written in CPP @NathanOliver. And the includes are in .C file. The other libs (writtin in C). Are working.

Comment: The.c files should be compiled as C code.  Otherwise they will most likely fail to compile since C and C++ are different languages.

Comment: It seems like you might be including a C header in a C++ source code file.

Answer (score 0):

in C++ `bool` is a keyword not a macro so the code above inside the `ifdef` is skipped and not compiled.

In C code sometimes `bool` is defined as a macro

```
#define bool int
#define true 1
#define false 0
```